# Comparing Time values in VBA throws Run-time error 13 'type mismatch'

Tags: vba, excel, runtime

Am trying to compare system time with the time stored in 2 adjacent cells. I tried the below comparison of times and it just works fine...

****this code worked fine****
Sub btn_Click()

```
 MsgBox Range("C4"), vbOKOnly, "Test"
 Dim time1 As Date
 Dim time2 As Date
 time1 = Time
 time2 = TimeValue(Cells(3, 1).Text)
 If time1 < time2 Then
      MsgBox str, vbOKOnly, "MsgIf"
 Else
      MsgBox str1, vbOKOnly, "MsgElse"
 End If
```

End Sub

---

but this doesn't work!!! the If condition throws error saying 'type mismatch'.
Please help!!!

```
Dim i As Integer
Dim w As Integer
Dim tm1 As Date
Dim tm2 As Date
Dim tm3 As Date
tm1 = Time

For i = 2 To 31
    tm2 = TimeValue(Cells(i, 1).Text)
    tm3 = TimeValue(Cells(i, 2).Text)

    If tm1 > tm2 & tm1 < tm3 Then ' this is the line that throws 'type mismatch' error
        Exit For
    End If
    Next i


MsgBox Cells(i, w), vbOKOnly, "Test"
```

Comment: change `If tm1 > tm2 & tm1 < tm3 Then` to `If tm1 > tm2 AND tm1 < tm3 Then`

Comment: VBA uses `And` for and, not &

Comment: If you were able to find a solution, please post it as an answer.

Answer (score 0):

For the sake of SO, I'll post the answer (in the comments) as an answer (instead of a comment). @Simoco or @Enderland, feel free to do the same and I'll remove my answer.

VBA does not use the `&` operator, nor the `|`. Instead, it respectively uses `And`and `Or`.

Answer (score 0):

Here it is:

VBA does not use the `&` operator, nor the `|`. Instead, it respectively uses `And` and `Or`.

Changing this

```
If tm1 > tm2 & tm1 < tm3 Then
```

to this

```
If tm1 > tm2 And tm1 < tm3 Then
```

solved the `Type Mismatch Error`.
thank you @simoco and @enderland

Comment: `&` is also used in VBA but it is used to combine `Strings`.

Comment: @L42 actually it's more than just combining two strings. It actually causes string concatenation, so you can actually combine other types (such as integers) like: `?"the" & 5` will return `the5`. This also lets you do string concatenation, however it is slightly more expansive.